# Problem with non linear restriction - state theta saturates and don't know how to apply an anti windup solution

Tags: matlab

### I'm doing a optimization problem using fmincon. I'm optimizing a given trajectory that a drone does. The drone is controlled by an MPC controller (implemented w/ fmincon).

So I made a plot of the trajectory and It goes alright:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuX8T.jpg (Here you can see both trajectory, states and the control).

The thing is, when I add a restriction to the angle that the drone does, that is |theta|<20º (see discretization.m), the trajectory becomes very curvy and I get this message from fmincon:
Solver stopped prematurely.
fmincon stopped because it exceeded the function evaluation limit,
options.MaxFunctionEvaluations = 30000 (the selected value).

And this is my result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrnEN.jpg
I think there is controller windup introduced by saturation (i.e. my limits on θ). I don't think this is a MATLAB/fmincon issue, but a control architecture issue. Maybe I should try to implement an anti-windup solution, but I have no idea how.

This is my code:  https://github.com/preguica00/mpc_drone_forces
If anyone could help me, that would be great. Thanks